# rvm and rubygems issues after upgrading rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I updated ruby gems with the following command:

```
gem update --system
```

Now I get the following error when running `bundle install` or just about any other gem command such as `gem -v`

```
/Users/darrenburgess/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- stringio (LoadError)
```

I can switch to the system ruby with `rvm use system`, and then `gem` commands seem to work, but I get the same error when I run `rvm use 2.0.0` even though the output of `rvm list` shows `=* ruby-2.0.0-p648 [ x86_64 ]` as the current and default. Note that I can switch to other installed version of ruby such as `2.4.1` and `2.1.2`.

When using system ruby the version of `gem` is 2.0.14.1

The version of RVM installed is 1.29.2 (current latest).

Output of `which -a ruby`
    /Users/darrenburgess/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby
    /usr/bin/ruby
    /Users/darrenburgess/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Per other issues that are similar I checked to make sure that the RVM directory is first in my $PATH variable. This path is first in line:

```
/Users/darrenburgess/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin
```

Unfortunately I am deeply into `knows enough to be dangerous` territory here. I believe what may be happening is that I have introduced incompatibility between my installed version of ruby/rubygems/rvm.

At this point I need help with different avenues to explore. Thank you.

UPDATE:
I have 3 versions of Ruby 2.0.0 installed as per `rvm list`

```
ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p648 [ x86_64 ]
```

I simply switched to using `p643` and that fixed the issue, in so much as I am not using the trashed version of ruby == `ruby-2.0.0-p648`

So I guess at this point I have sidestepped the issue and the question now is simply what is wrong with `ruby-2.0.0-p648` and how can it be fixed?

More information:
`ruby-2.0.0-p643` is using `gem` version `2.4.6`
`ruby-2.0.0-p481` is using `gem` version `2.2.2`
The current latest version of rubygems is `2.6.12`

So I suspect that I upgraded rubygems to a version incompatible with ruby 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to fix the issue, but I am still uncertain as to why upgrading rubygems caused these issues.

Fix was to:

```
rvm remove ruby-2.0.0-p648
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p648
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

So it seems removing the ruby version removes all of the installed gems and perhaps also the incompatible version of rubygems that I installed. Reinstalling ruby 2.0.0p648 resolved the issue.